# Как сделать многоуровневое меню в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот

Всем привет!
Не судите строго, я новичок в программировании. Возникла потребность в создании бота в телеграмме, который будет содержать в себе каталог. Структура: Категории(кнопки)=>Подкатегории(кнопки)=>Товары(кнопки)=> Описание товара и фото(текст и картинка). Но столкнулся с проблемой после подкатегорий не появляются кнопки товаров. Что я делаю не так?)))
И ещё вопрос, я хочу, чтобы после выбора товара отправлялись описание и картинка, правильный ли я кода использую? Пример кода:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
from requests import get

bot=telebot.TeleBot('ТОКЕН')

# выбираем категории

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def category(message):
    keyboard_category = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    key_1_1 = types.KeyboardButton('1_1')
     keyboard_category.add(key_1_1)

    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет! Я помогу подобрать товар!",
                reply_markup=keyboard_category)

# выбираем подкатегории

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def subcategory(message):
    if message.text == "1_1":
        keyboard_subcategory = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        key_2_1 = types.KeyboardButton('2_1')
        keyboard_subcategory.add(2_1)

        bot.send_message(message, 'Выберите подкатегорию', reply_markup=keyboard_subcategory)

# выбираем товар из подкатегории 

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def tovar(message):
    if message.text == "2_1":
        keyboard_tovar = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        key_3_1 = types.KeyboardButton('3_1')
        keyboard_tovar.add(key_id1)

        bot.send_message(message, 'Выберите товар по названию и я пришлю вам подробности', 
                                   reply_markup= keyboard_tovar)

@bot.message_handler(content_types = ['text'])
def abc(message):
   if message.text == "3_1"
       bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Описание товара")
       bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, get("Ссылка на картинку").content)

bot.polling()
```

Comment: зачем вам куча хендлеров на обработку текста, если можно сделать всё в одном? первый будет `if`, последующие `elif`. а вообще посмотрите в сторону `inline` кнопокй

Answer (score 1):

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def category(message):
    keyboard_category = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    key_1_1 = types.KeyboardButton('1_1')
    keyboard_category.add(key_1_1)

    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет! Я помогу подобрать товар!", reply_markup=keyboard_category)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def subcategory(message):
    if message.text == "1_1":
        keyboard_subcategory = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        key_2_1 = types.KeyboardButton('2_1')
        keyboard_subcategory.add(key_2_1)  # key_2_1 не использовалась

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите подкатегорию', reply_markup=keyboard_subcategory)

    elif message.text == "2_1":
        keyboard_tovar = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        key_3_1 = types.KeyboardButton('3_1')
        keyboard_tovar.add(key_3_1)  # key_3_1 не использовалась

        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Выберите товар по названию и я пришлю вам подробности',
                         reply_markup=keyboard_tovar)

    elif message.text == "3_1":  # потеряли двоеточие
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Описание товара")
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, 'https://cs13.pikabu.ru/images/big_size_comm/2020-06_3/159194100716237333.jpg')  # просто укажите ссылку на картинку


bot.polling()
```

и пример на `inline` кнопках:

```
def keyboard(where_call):
    kb = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    if where_call == 'start':
        kb_1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='1_1_inline', callback_data='1_1_inline')
        kb.add(kb_1)
        return kb
    elif where_call == 'subcategory':
        kb_2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='2_1_inline', callback_data='2_1_inline')
        kb.add(kb_2)
        return kb
    elif where_call == 'product':
        kb_3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='3_1_inline', callback_data='3_1_inline')
        kb.add(kb_3)
        return kb


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def category(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Привет! Я помогу подобрать товар!", reply_markup=keyboard('start'))


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_inline(call):
    if call.data == '1_1_inline':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text='подкатегория', reply_markup=keyboard('subcategory'))
    elif call.data == '2_1_inline':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text='товар', reply_markup=keyboard('product'))
    elif call.data == '3_1_inline':
        bot.edit_message_text(chat_id=call.message.chat.id, message_id=call.message.message_id,
                              text='Описание товара')
        bot.send_photo(call.message.chat.id,
                       'https://cs13.pikabu.ru/images/big_size_comm/2020-06_3/159194100716237333.jpg')
```